# phpmyadmin shows "file not found" on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to configure phpmyadmin on nginx so it'll be available on http://server_IP:8081/phpmyadmin

When I enter, I get: "File not found."

Those are my settings:

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name _;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        auth_basic           "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/htpasswd;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_error.log;
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     
        $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if PHPMyAdmin is installed properly,
Have you tried making a symbolic link from nginx root. if you haven't try doing that , it might help

Comment: Wha't do you mean by "symbolic link from nginx root"?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't mention it. try this sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html